# Is there a way to mark multiple properties as get only in a protocol?

Tags: swift

I'm wondering if there's a way to do something like:

`NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` and `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END`

but with protocol properties:

```
protocol Person {
    SWIFT_ASSUME_GET_BEGIN
    var name: String
    var dob: Date
    var address: String
    SWIFT_ASSUME_GET_END
}
```

opposed to:

```
protocol Person {
    var name: String { get }
    var dob: Date { get }
    var address: String { get }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there's a way to do something like:

```
    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

> but with protocol properties,

Well, there isn’t.

> Thanks

You’re welcome.